# Udp hybrid app using phonegap and ios

Tags: ios, html, hybrid-mobile-app

i had intergrated a button into the ui of phonegap, i would like to send udp commands to a particular server, how do i do that??

html part:

```
<button id="sync" onclick="showToast1()" value="3C0055">sync</button>
```

Script part:

```
function showToast1(sender: AnyObject) {
                var byte:[UInt8] = [ 0x3c, 0x00, 0x55]
                var data = NSData(bytes: byte, length: 5)
                mUdpSocket.sendData(data, toHost: "IP", port:"number", withTimeout: 2, tag: 0)

            }
```